# aligning select box in table

Tags: html, css

I have this issue at the moment

[image: text and select box not aligned in table]

So far these aren't aligned. I could do with aligning them but i'm not sure how to go about this. Here is the code

HTML

```
<table class="table">
          <tr>
        <td colspan="2" ng-if="eventData.early_bird && !eventData.member">
          {{package.eb_before}}
          <div align="right">
          <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </td>
```

Comment: @ddsbro can you provide some demo code with it.?

Comment: Replace `align="right"` with `style="float: right;"`

Comment: Yep the float method worked fine !

Comment: or, to further @putvande answer,  put a class on the div `<div class="table_opts">` and in your css put `.table_opts{float:right;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `align="right"` (or `align`) has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align). Better to just use `float`, something like this would work:

```
<div style="float: right">
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dbdkhqh/).

You don't really even need the `div`. You could place the `style="float: right"` on the `select` itself.